# Using mvnDebug crashes with 'Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice error'

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I was building a simple project, a hello world example with teserract [1]. This worked fine in the Linux environment and when i tried it in the Mac it failed. So i wanted to debug the build process and see what's wrong. So i used,

```
mvnDebug clean install
```

but im getting this error immediately after running this,

```
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp
```

Im using java 1.8. So what does this error means ?

[1] - https://github.com/nirojans/receipt-ocr

Answer (score 1):

This means you're debbugging with duplicate arguments, check `%JAVA_OPTIONS%` in the log and remove one of these args and it should work!